# How to implement a two-way binding mechanism?

Tags: flutter, dart

When you observe carefully the binding mechanism between a **TextField** and a **TextEditingController**, you will realize that there's a two-way binding between these two. Therefore, any direct changes to a **TextField** will notify and update its **TextEditingController**. Likewise, any direct changes to a **TextEditingController** will notify and update its **TextField**.

Now let's try to implement a two-way binding mechanism. Consider the following example:

```
class NotificationValue {
  final String subject;
  final String message;

  const NotificationValue({
    required this.subject,
    required this.message,
  });

  NotificationValue copyWith({
    String? subject,
    String? message,
  }) {
    return NotificationValue(
      subject: subject ?? this.subject,
      message: message ?? this.message,
    );
  }
}

class NotificationController extends ValueNotifier<NotificationValue> {
  NotificationController({
    String subject = '',
    String message = '',
  }) : super(NotificationValue(
          subject: subject,
          message: message,
        ));

  String get subject => value.subject;
  String get message => value.message;

  set subject(String nextValue) {
    value = value.copyWith(
      subject: nextValue,
    );
  }

  set message(String nextValue) {
    value = value.copyWith(
      message: nextValue,
    );
  }
}

class NotificationInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationInput({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final NotificationController controller;

  @override
  State<NotificationInput> createState() => _NotificationInputState();
}

class _NotificationInputState extends State<NotificationInput> {
  final subjectController = TextEditingController();
  final messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    subjectController.text = widget.controller.subject;
    messageController.text = widget.controller.message;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subjectController.dispose();
    messageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(controller: subjectController),
        TextField(controller: messageController),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the **NotificationController** provides notifications in the form of a **NotificationValue**. Essentially, it's following the design pattern of the **TextEditingController** which provides notifications in the form of a **TextEditingValue**.

Now, let's present the programming question: How can you create a two-way binding between the **NotificationInput** and the **NotificationController**. Therefore, any direct changes to a **NotificationInput** will notify and update its **NotificationController**. Likewise, any direct changes to a **NotificationController** will notify and update its **NotificationInput**.

WARNING: remember that there exists the potential for a circular deadlock (that is, when the UI and controller keep notifying each other in an infinite loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use listener with check if values are not equal to achieve this. Replace initState with following code

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    subjectController.text = widget.controller.subject;
    messageController.text = widget.controller.message;

    subjectController.addListener(() {
      if (subjectController.text != widget.controller.subject) {
        widget.controller.subject = subjectController.text;
      }
    });

    messageController.addListener(() {
      if (messageController.text != widget.controller.message) {
        widget.controller.message = messageController.text;
      }
    });

    widget.controller.addListener(() {
      if (subjectController.text != widget.controller.subject) {
        subjectController.text = widget.controller.subject;
      }
      if (messageController.text != widget.controller.message) {
        messageController.text = widget.controller.message;
      }
    });
  }
```